# 2D NSMutable arrays and some musings on NSMutable arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to comprehend how I can create multi-dimensional NSMutable arrays in general. I have come across a few solutions but haven't been able to make them work for me, so I am not sure of their validity. Now if only someone here can help me understand how to create 2-D NSMutable arrays better that would be great!

Moving to the next question, I am not sure when I should summon NSArray/NSMutableArray vs simply using a C array. In the particular case I am dealing with, I have a fixed data type 
that I want to use (boolean values) and these are clearly not objects. NS and NSMutableArray are meant to hold objects, if I am not mistaken. So is this a good idea to use a regular C array vs NSMutable array?

Adding a final twist to the question on creating 2D arrays, is using NSMatrices a better alternative or even an option than creating 2D NSMutable arrays?

Thanks and major high fives to all those who read and answer this!

Comment: There's no such thing as a two-dimensional `NSArray`, but it sounds like you're working backward from an assumption about an implementation to the problem you're trying to solve. You might get a more useful answer if you start from the other direction (i.e., by describing the problem space).

Comment: Well my aim is to create a 2-D array, of 3 rows and 3 columns, where I can enter data of boolean type and retrieve values, does that explain better?

Comment: A more meaningful question might be when should you use C arrays instead of NSArray?  Nested array are the common idiom used for n-dimensional arrays, and NSValue is used to store primitive types.

Comment: NSMatrix is not for storing data but it is a special type of control: It can display a grid of cells (buttons, check boxes, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create 2D array using NSMutableArrays you would need to do the following:

```
// Create the 2D array
// array2D is created autoreleased. It should be retained somewhere
// to keep it around. 
NSMutableArray* array2D = [NSMutableArray array];

// Add a NSMutableArray to array2D for each row
NSUInteger countRows = 8; // Or whatever value you need
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < countRows; i++) {
  NSMutableArray* row = [NSMutableArray array];
  [array2D addObject:row];
}
```

Note that you can add additional rows to array2D at any time. Also each row starts out
with size 0 and is empty. You can add different number of elements to each row so it
is a jagged 2D array rather than something more like a matrix which would be fixed size
(i.e. M rows x N columns.)

To set a value at a specific row and column you would do the following:

```
NSUInteger rowIndex = 5;
NSUInteger columnIndex = 7;
NSNumber* value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:11];

// Get the 6th row
// Make sure there are 6 rows
NSUInteger countRows = array2d.count;
if (countRows >= (rowIndex + 1)) {
  NSMutableArray* row = (NSMutableArray*)[array2d objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
  // Get the 8th column
  // Make sure there are 8 columns
  NSUInteger countColumns = row.count;
  if (countColumns >= (columnIndex + 1)) {
    // Set the value
    [row setObject:value atIndex:columnIndex];
  }
}
```

You can store C types in NSMutableArrays by wrapping them in ObjectiveC objects.
A number can be translated into an object using NSNumber. NSNumber can also wrap boolean
values. Pointers to C structs can be wrapped using NSValue objects. You can also create
NSValue objects that wrap specific Cocoa types, e.g. CGRect.

```
int intValue = 1;
NSNumber* number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:intValue];

BOOL boolValue = NO;
NSNumber* number = [NSNumber numberWithBool:boolValue];
```

NSArrays are not modifiable. If you need to add or remove objects to an array, you should you an NSMutableArray. Otherwise use a NSArray.

NSMutableArrays and NSArrays retain the objects that are added to them, taking ownership of them. When an object is removed from an NSMutableArray it is released so that it is cleaned up. When you release an NSArray or an NSMutableArray that you no longer require, they will clean up any objects that you have added to the array. This makes memory management of 
objects within arrays much easier.

You can't add nil objects to NSArrays and NSMutableArrays.

NSMutableArray is dynamically resizing whilst C arrays are not. This makes it much easier 
to deal with adding and removing objects to the array.

I would use a C array for a group of C types, e.g. ints that is fixed size and 
whose values are known at compile time:

```
int knownConstantValues[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

You might need to use a C array to pass data to a library with a C API, e.g. OpenGL.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Brian, thanks for the detailed explanation, one question pertaining to your point upon using C arrays whose value is known at compile times. In my case, the size of the 2-d array is fixed at n X n, and it is of the type boolean. However, what boolean value goes into what cell is determined at run time depending on user input. Isn't this possible to go ahead with ?

Comment: You could definitely use a C array in that case. It would probably be the easier and more elegant solution

Comment: So this is what I am learning from the whole conversation above: use c-arrays when the array is expected to provide minimal functionality and is storing primitive data types vs Objective-C objects?
Thanks !